# Magento Listings error

Tags: magento

Hello i am having an error in my magento webshop. On certain grouped products. There should be a div class listing for every row. But on some grouped product pages the listing for the first row goes wrong. Which then results in the whole page going wrong. When i check the page source. I see that the second row has been put inside the first row. For an example http://msk.clicksite.nl/pleisters-en-antidruk/anti-druk-middelen?p=1. The strange thing is if you go to page 2 the error is gone.

I hope someone has experienced this problem or knows what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a magento issue, looks like design issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your product description.  You have an open tag that's messing your design up.

```
            <div class="product-content">
                <ul><li>Zelfklevend beschermpleister 2 mm.</li> <li>Ook verkrijgbaar als fleecy foam 5 mm.</...
            </div>
```

To fix it, go into your product description and remove the unordered list formatting `<ul><li>`.  A permanent solution would be to go to your template and edit the code that's truncating the description.  Strip all of the html from it and you should be all set.  Try `/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/catalog/product/list.phtml`